# Public IP address of my router from an Android Device connected to another network

Tags: android, networking, ip

I want to take the public Ip address of my router in Android. But in case that my Android device is connected to another network (3G) and not in router's wifi. Is there a way to achieve that or do I need to use a domain name service?

Comment: Huh?  If your device is connected via a completely different route, how could it possibly know anything about some random router?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth :-) Don't know my friend. I thought if there is something in my router that it is unique and can be recognized with this.Because my public ip always changing. As I'm understanding there isn't, right?

Comment: Unless your ISP gives you a static address, something like no-ip.org which does a free dns is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you took your router address and added it to your phone, the address is owned by your ISP, so all data from that address is sent to your ISP and not to your cell phone provider. This means data sent to that IP address will never get to the 3G network, let alone your phone.